# Is Nagorno-Karabakh recognized as Azerbaijani territory by the West?

Tags: azerbaijan, armenia

Prior to the war of 2020 it seems like Nagorno-Karabakh remained recognized as Azerbaijani territory by most international organizations. Does this remain the case after the war? Have there been any official statements since the war on who has legal rights to Nagorno-Karabakh?

Comment: Why would it change? Have there been any official statements on who has legal rights to California?

Comment: @alamar I haven’t seen much cheering from the West over Azerbaijan reclaiming it’s legal territory so I’m not sure what the status is. Seems like the war was a good thing if you legally treated Armenia as a hostile occupant of Azerbaijani land. I imagine the West won’t be so silent if Ukraine recaptures Crimea.

Comment: China recapturing Taiwan, Serbia recapturing Kosovo? The West just does not like Azerbaijan that much, since it is shi'a muslim, big friends with NATO renegade Turkey and is a danger to local power equilibrium in trans-Caucasus.

Comment: Taiwan and Kosovo are different because they’re breakaway nations trying to claim sovereignty. Nagorno-Karabakh was captured by Armenia and never aimed to be independent (although it was on paper).

Comment: The Republic of Artsakh, however, did. It coincided to overlap with what Azerbaijan consides its province.

Comment: @alamar it was just legal fiction, a sort of a fig leaf by Armenia until full recognition could be obtained

Comment: I'm not sure how it is different fom Kosovo with Albania behind the fig leaf. Artsakh even has a football team in league of partially recognized countries tournament. Also it have been independent for 30 years now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The position of the West expressed during and after [the 2020 war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Nagorno-Karabakh_War) is that the two sides should negotiate under the auspices of the Organization for Security and Co-operation in Europe (OSCE), and reach a mutually agreed settlement. The US and UK have not stated exactly what settlement they wish to see.

In November 2020, the UK government stated its [position in a message to the OSCE](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/uk-statement-on-situation-in-and-around-nagorno-karabakh-12-november-2020), which is that a settlement should be negotiated between the belligerents at negotiations organised by the OSCE, through a structure known as the The [OSCE Minsk Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSCE_Minsk_Group).

> The UK would like to reiterate its support for the OSCE Minsk Group as the primary format through which any final settlement is reached.

On October 8, the [US issued a similar statement](https://osce.usmission.gov/u-s-statement-on-the-situation-regarding-nagorno-karabakh/), calling for a ceasefire and negotiated settlement under the auspices of the Minsk Group.

Hence rather than taking a position on what form the final status of Nagorno-Karabakh should be, they would prefer the parties to negotiate a fair agreement under international guidance.

Comment: But do the US and UK continue to recognize Nagorno-Karabakh as Azerbaijani territory by right? Or does that remain intentionally ambiguous?

Comment: Because previous negotiations via Minsk Group worked so well in stopping violence...